# Is OAuth2 a stand alone authentication/authorization system?

Tags: ember.js, oauth-2.0, laravel

I'd like to develop an app using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) to build the API and have an [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/) front end consuming the API. [Sentry](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/overview) seems to be the go-to for authorization and authentication for Laravel so i thought i'd use that. I've also read that it's a good idea to use OAuth2 to lock down your API.

Does OAuth2 replace something like Sentry or work in unison with it?

And if i were to use OAuth2 how would that work with the EmberJS front end? Would i have to register the ember front end as a separate app for OAuth2 to work?

I'm a bit confused on how these pieces should work together.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 is a spec and have many implementations. The [official website](http://oauth.net/2/) lists a few. 
I looked around and found [this one](https://github.com/amkirwan/ember-oauth2) for Ember.js (https://github.com/amkirwan/ember-oauth2). Hope it helps.